# Background width for individual text lines

Tags: html, css

Basically what I want to do, considering the example below, is to create a fluid and dynamic background width depending on the text size with more than one line. This because I have set a justified text alignment and at some point (e.g. in the second line) the text doesn't fill up all the width of the background, which is enlarged by the upper sentence which is bigger. I don't want the background to fill it up! I don't know if I'm making myself clear, but I'll try to explain with the example below.

http://jsfiddle.net/gcAhL/

**HTML**

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://s23.postimg.org/g033nno17/image.jpg">
    <div class="title">This is a title</div>    
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://s23.postimg.org/g033nno17/image.jpg">
    <div class="title">This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title</div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 530px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.title {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #CCC;
    text-align: justify;
    max-width: 600px;
    bottom: 30px;
    padding: 5px;       
}
```

As you can see, the last blue square has text that breaks into two lines. The greyish background fills up the width basing itself on the first line. What I want to happen is that in the second line, the grey fills the text of that line only.

Example: http://s9.postimg.org/634pzc9y7/example.jpg

Is this even possible? Thanks in advance for all the responses.

Comment: Did you try `display: inline-block`?

Comment: @bfavaretto that will break the position of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `<span>` element inside of your `<div>` and give background-color to `<span>` element instead of `<div>`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://s23.postimg.org/g033nno17/image.jpg">
    <div class="title"><span>This is a title</span></div>    
</div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://s23.postimg.org/g033nno17/image.jpg">
        <div class="title"><span>This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title This is a title</span></div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image {
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 530px;
    margin: 10px;
}
span{background-color: #CCC;}
.title {
    position: absolute;
    line-height:100%;
    text-align: justify;
    max-width: 600px;
    bottom: 30px;
    padding: 5px;       
}
```

Comment: And isn't there other way? That works great, but when using opacity in background color and padding, they will overlay each other.

Comment: you can wrap your span with another span :)

Comment: Nice one. Any way to make the second line have left padding aswell?

Comment: Nice one. Even though it doesn't work in my case since I'm not using <br>

Comment: did u try to give margin to inner span?

Comment: Well yes but it influences the whole sentence.